# How does an airline/ground handling company send a notification to Russian authorities?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, russia, lost-documents

The concerned person, a dual Swedish-Russian citizen, intends to fly PRN-BUD-LED with Wizz.

Regarding her Russian citizenship, the only document she has is an internal passport, as she had her international passport stolen not too long ago.

Per TIMATIC, this document is valid for entering Russia:

> ***Passport Exemptions: Nationals of the Russian Fed. with a domestic passport (written only in Russian)***

but with the following note:

> ***Warning: For nationals of the Russian Fed. with a domestic passport (written only in Russian), carrier must send prior notification to the
>   port of entry and obtain approval from Russian border Police.***

My question is: how is this done, and by whom?

Is it something the passenger should E-Mail Wizz about after making the reservation, or will the ground handling Company (if so, at PRN or BUD?) automatically send some sort of message at check-in to the Russians (such as via SITA Telex)?

P.S. if anyone wonders, the exit will be through Belarus, which in turn accepts the internal passport for exit to anywhere (unlike Russia)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Russian Constitution, Russian Citizens cannot be stopped from returning to Russia, so, even if your friend does not have the international passport, (s)he can return back to Russia with internal passport.

However, such situation will lead to administrative fee about a 3000 RUR during border control, and it may take up to 2 hours to go through all that procedure.

What your friend can do is to contact the nearest Russian Consulate or Embassy and get the special document for such situations called `Свидетельство на возвращение в Россию` (Certificate for return to Russia), which is being used exactly for such situations. After getting this document one should use that document for check-in within carrier. Please note that such document cannot be used to go outside the Russia.

Documents needed for this certificate is:

- Internal Russian passport
- Filled questionnaire obtained in Consulate/Embassy
- 2 photos

If your friend cannot get the certificate in time, (s)he should notify the Wiss that the passport for check-in will be the internal. It's not look like that they need to do something special in that case.

Comment: TIMATIC clearly says she doesn't need that certificate - but **either** that **or** an internal passport. But it says that with only an internal passport, a confirmation from Russia is to be obtained by the carrier (I guess it's so that the Russians can do the necessary checks in advance to avoid delays). What I want to know is how that procedure works.

Comment: As I said, you notify the carrier, and they do necessary steps for you. There still will be delays for your friend, as the procedure of issuing the fee for crossing the border without the passport still takes time, and they still will do checks on border control.

Comment: Right, OK!.....

Comment: If you'll have some more information about your case resolved, probably worth to add your own answer lately